# Resolving async function after a loop end

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I expect when I call an async function to resolve promise at the end, not before.

```
const urls = await uploadImages({ imageChanges, questions });
// ...next step
// I will use urls
```

But after calling `await uploadImages()` it continues to run until `const data = await fetch(image.src);`

And then `...next step` starts. How can I make it wait for `imageChanges.forEach` loop finish ? Should I create another nested function inside ?

```
const uploadImages = async ({ imageChanges, questions }) => {
    if (!imageChanges.length) return null;

    const storage = firebase.storage();
    let urls; 

    try {
        //** convert each new image's src from blob to downloadUrl. */
        imageChanges.forEach(async image => {
            const questionId = questions.findIndex(q => q.id === image.questionId);
            const imagePath = `${questionId}.jpg`;
            const storageRef = storage.ref(imagePath);

            // ** 
            const data = await fetch(image.src);
            const blob = await data.blob();

            const uploadTaskSnapshot = await storageRef.put(blob);
            const downloadURL = await uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
            urls.push(downloadURL)
        });

        return urls;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
};
```

Comment: I am trying to understand your question, are you saying,  after you call `await uploadImages({ imageChanges, questions });`, when the loop in completed it starts the next steps and still the loop tat completed fetches the images in background ?

Comment: I edited question. I want it return "urls" to me. But before "const data = await fetch(image.src);" code line, my caller function's next line starts to run without waiting urls. And some time later it goes back to "uploadImages" function

Comment: you may find related info in these answers, https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/3270433

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript does this because `forEach` is not promise-aware. It cannot support `async` and `await`. You cannot use `await` in forEach.

If you use `await` in a `map`, `map` will always return an array of promises. This is because asynchronous functions always return promises.

By littile modification to your code, this should work,

```
const uploadImages = async ({ imageChanges, questions }) => {
if (!imageChanges.length) return null;

const storage = firebase.storage();
let urls;

try {
    //** convert each new image's src from blob to downloadUrl. */
    await Promise.all(imageChanges.map(async image => {
        const questionId = questions.findIndex(q => q.id === image.questionId);
        const imagePath = `${questionId}.jpg`;
        const storageRef = storage.ref(imagePath);

        // **
        const data = await fetch(image.src);
        const blob = await data.blob();

        const uploadTaskSnapshot = await storageRef.put(blob);
        const downloadURL = await uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
        urls.push(downloadURL)
    }));

    return urls;
 } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
 }
};

const urls = await uploadImages({ imageChanges, questions });
```

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` with async doesn't work as expected. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop) for more info.

Try like this

```
const uploadImages = async ({ imageChanges, questions }) => {
  if (!imageChanges.length) return null;

  const storage = firebase.storage();

  try {
    const imageChangesUrlPromise = imageChanges.map(async () => {
      const questionId = questions.findIndex(q => q.id === image.questionId);
      const imagePath = `${questionId}.jpg`;
      const storageRef = storage.ref(imagePath);
      const data = await fetch(image.src);
      const blob = await data.blob();
      const uploadTaskSnapshot = await storageRef.put(blob);
      const downloadURL = await uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
      return downloadURL;
    })

    return await Promise.all(imageChangesUrlPromise);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};
```

and then

```
const urls = await uploadImages({ imageChanges, questions });
...
```